# "One more" and "Another"

Tags: difference

Are "one more" and "another" interchangeable? When are they not interchangeable?

- Please, give me one more (another) chance.
- You can take one more (another) apple from the table.
- There's one more (another) thing left to do.
- If you take one more (another) step I will shoot.

Answer (score 5):

Few things in language are “always interchangeable.”

One obvious example here is when these phrases are preceded by the word “only”:

> There is only one more thing left to do.

That is normal, idiomatic speech. However, this is not, and it sounds a little awkward:

> There is only another thing left to do.

Comment: Intriguingly, by comparison, *just another thing*, doesn't sound awkward to me.